# Package [some package] is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

On `dotnet restore` we are receiving the following error:

> Package Microsoft.AspNet.SomePackage 5.6.7 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNet.SomePackage 5.6.7 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Our project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SomePackage": "5.6.7",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win8-x64": {}
  }
}
```

How can we `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run` in a way that runs our app?

Comment: what frameworks does `Microsoft.AspNet.SomePackage` target?

Comment: The error says that it, "supports: net45".

Comment: `"Microsoft.AspNet.SomePackage": "5.6.7",` Chances are, you are referencing an ASP.NET Core RC1 assembly or even an ASP.NET 4.5 package. The new ASP.NET Core assemblies got remaned in rc2 to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` (from `Microsoft.AspNet.*`). Another hint for this is that it uses a version >= 0. With the rename to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` all versions got reset to 1.0.0- (EF, ASP.NET and MVC related assemblies)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. In some narrow cases you can use imports to override nuget's built in dependency rules. In this case you cannot, .NET Framework and .NET Core are incompatible. The errors says the package only supports net45 (.NET Framework 4.5). You cannot use it with your .NET Core application

Comment: Okay. So [`imports`](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/projectjson-format#imports) allow us to use dependencies (packages) that do not target our project's `framework`, if and only if those dependencies do target a framework that is compatible with our project's framework. Is that right?

Comment: Hi @davidfowl, we can't compile now our applications if we migrate to RC2 until packages are updated to .NET Core?

Comment: Were you using .NET Core before or were you using .NET Framework? You can convert your project to ASP.NET on .NET Framework, but if your dependencies don't have a .NET Core version then you cannot move to .NET Core (unless you remove/rewrite those dependencies)

Answer (score 19):

Note - by adding "net451" to the framework imports I was able to make it work.

```
"frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
         "net451",
         "dotnet5.6",
         "portable-net45+win8"
       ]
   }
},
```

I took it from [here](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/275)

Comment: I too have an old library which target .net framework 4.5 and this solved my issue. Are there any side-effects for doing this?

Comment: Hi @Sobhan probably the side effect is that you will need .net framework 4.5 in your server. The advantage of using core is that you can deploy in a linux server.

Comment: This is unfortunate, as the main reason for going .net Core is to remove the dependency on the OS type.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to do the same thing but are using the new .csproj for configuration rather than the project.json, edit your .csproj file and add the following right below the  propertygroup:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>net451;dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj).

Answer (score 0):

requirejs is on github (https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs) and it is possible to compile it with core as dependency.

If the package is open source or the source is available then it is possible to recompile with dot net core instead for 4.5 framework.
It all depends on other other dependencies and their compatibility with dotnet core.