# How to make ASP.NET Core RC2 app build on net46 framework with older third party dependencies

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc, dotnet-cli

I have a shiny new Asp.Net Core MVC App that references some older `net45` libraries.

Works fine with Asp.Net Core RC1 on full net45 framework. Migrating from Asp.NET Core rc1 to rc2 I have hit an obstacle that I don't know how to fix.

The App is a ASP.NET Core App that using EF6, Autofac, Kendo.MVC and it needs to run on the full .Net 4.6 framework as there are references libraries that use WCF.

In migrating from rc1 to rc2 I first update the NuGet.config feed to point to `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json` then I make the following changes to the `project.json`

- Remove "version" from the top most node
- Add the following attribute to the complationOptions object: "debugType": "portable"
- dependencies: change `AspNet` to `AspNetCore`
- dependencies: change all `rc1-final`, to `*`
- Check that `MVC` and `MVC Tag Helpers` have been renamed from `6.0` to `1.0`
- Remove all dependencies to `Application Insights`
- Remove all dependencies for `Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor`
- Add a dependency to  `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {  "type": "platform",  "version": "1.0.0-*"  }`
- Add a new content object:  `"content": [  "wwwroot", "Views",  "web.config", "appsettings.json" ]`

  - Update all using statements to reference `AspNetCore.*` instead of `AspNet.*`

I then replace the frameworks object with:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "net45"
    ]
  }
}
```

I do a `dotnet restore` and everything resolves exceptfor 1 package:

```
error: Package Kendo.Mvc 2016.1.412 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Kendo.Mvc 2016.1.412 supports:
error:   - dnx451 (DNX,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
info : Committing restore...


Errors in project.json
    Package Kendo.Mvc 2016.1.412 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Kendo.Mvc 2016.1.412 supports:
      - dnx451 (DNX,Version=v4.5.1)
      - dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

So, Kendo.MVC needs to reference `net45` or `net451` instead of `dnx451`, but since this comes from a NuGet feed, I can't change this.

Do you know if there is a quick fix I can make instead of waiting for the next release of Kendo.MVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is close. Well done. There are a few changes/additions to make. The following works with `dotnet restore` then `dotnet run`. The [full code listing is on GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/AspNetCoreKendoMvc).

### frameworks

Your `frameworks` fail because [.NET Core (`netcoreapp`) is not compatible with .NET Framework (`net`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932453/1108891), so you cannot import `net45`. Your errors say that `Kendo.Mvc` is compatible with `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`; import one of those instead. Then add a portable import for some packages on which `Kendo.Mvc` depends (if you don't, you will see build errors that tell you to do this.)

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8+wp8"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now your app will restore and build. It won't run yet, though.

## dependencies

Change your dependency on `Microsoft.NETCore.App` not to have the [`"type" : "platform"`](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2303). Otherwise your app will not run on its own, because NuGet will suppress the package's assets.

```
"dependencies" : 
{
    // others omitted for clarity
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0-*",
    "Kendo.Mvc": "*"
}
```

## runtimes

Add a [`runtimes`](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/projectjson-format#runtimes) section; we now specify this in project.json instead of relying on `dnvm`.

```
"runtimes": {
  "win8-x64": {}
}
```

Comment: Great response! I was mixing up netcoreapp1.0 and netstandard1.5 and now realise that `netstandard` is not a 'thing' yet.   Your references to the Nuget [`project.json`](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/projectjson-format#runtimes) is invaluable. I had missed that. I will update the question to use the correct netcoreapp1.0 and you can remove this from answer as it may mislead others.