# Is it possible to fix "Package is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0"? How?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

> I know there are some other questions related to this but none provided a realy good answer to the subject and on how to fix the problem. Here is a related question: [Package [some package] is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898339/package-some-package-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp1-0)

In my case running dotnet restore throws "Package is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)"

And this is what I would like to know so I could fix the problem

- Is it possible to determine which dotnet core version is required by the package being installed?
- Is it possible to use `dotnet new` to prepare a project running a lower core version preferably targeting the version determined in the previous step
- Rebuilding the source code from the project will ensure compatibility with the netcoreapp1.0

**This is the package location**
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/

**And this is the repository**
https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient

PS: I'm using MacOS and Visual Studio Code 2016

Comment: There's nothing you can do. That package isn't targetted to .Net Core. You may be able to get around it by writing a .Net 4.x library and using it as a pass through, but that defeats the object of using .Net Core.

Comment: Looks like there is already an issue raised on their tracker: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-682