# Square-Connect API compatibility with ASP .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, square-connect

I'm working with a client on an application that uses ASP .NET core. When I `Package Square.Connect 2.0.2.71 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0`. I was wondering if the API supports ASP .NET core.

Comment: The APIs are, but the SDK might not be. There might be some useful tips in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898339/package-some-package-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp1-0)

Comment: I've ported the sdk to netstandard because I need to use it in asp.net core https://github.com/joeaudette/square.netstandard