# netcoreapp1.0 not compatible with net45

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core-mvc

3 hours of googling and I still can't find an answer
I tried this also: [Package [some package] is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898339/package-some-package-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp1-0)
Still doesn't work, I even added net45 and net40 reference on the imports. Another is problem is my mvc core project doesnt have a package.json

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are probably using VS2017, you won't have a project.json since it doesn't exist any longer. So, doing the following will get you to hopefully a working project.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" Version="2.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

right click your project file edit `.csproj`, then `remove and replace the <propertygroup> </propertygroup>` and it's contents. Should work now to reference signalr packages.  The unfortunate fun is you have to create  your own middleware to tie it into the core framework..

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115941/ASP-NET-Core-Building-a-Real-Time-Online-Poll-Syst

I did create the middleware really quick and it does compile.  Whether it works I hadn't gotten that far. Keep in mind that link references the really old stuff before VS2017 and .csproj files for the projects.

hope that helps.

Comment: THANK YOU! I also added net40 and net451 to get it to work btw